# Reporting offensive usernames

Tags: discussion

Can a username be flagged as offensive?   Are there guidelines for what would reasonably be considered offensive?

Answer (score 2):

Sure; flag one of their posts and indicate that you consider the username offensive. Unless it is obvious, indicate why as well.